# Links on iframe creates another view of page in IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, target

I created a html and used it as a source of an iframe.

In iframe, I added a link on div (See sample code below)

```
<div onclick="location.href='/cybersecurity/risk-management/index.cfm'; location.href='_parent';" >
    <b>Sample Text</b><br />
    <span>
        Sample Text
    </span>
</div>
```

When I tried to click the div inside the page of iframe. It creates another view of the page inside the iframe. But for anchors in the iframe works fine, `<a href="linkhere" target="_parent" >This is an anchor!</a>`. How can I add JavaScript on `onClick` of my div?

I also tried to use `<base target="_parent" />`, yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `window.location.href`, which is the current window (the iframe), you want to set the location of the top most window (the parent).

```
window.top.location.href = 'foobar'
```

You can also use `window.parent` which will use the immediate parent window of the current one, but in most cases it's safer to use `window.top`since you actually want to top most parent window.

Comment: Thanks! :D I never regret to explain my problems here. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

```
<div onclick="parent.document.location.href='/cybersecurity/risk-management/index.cfm';" >
    <b>Sample Text</b><br />
    <span>
        Sample Text
    </span>
</div>
```

That would trigger you parent view to a change url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent

Comment: This thing also work, but I have to give @Jamie Dixon a credit who answer my question first. Thanks though! +1 upvote for you!